# How can I see the proportion for each answer while making it a tibble?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a tibble that will allow me to see the proportion for each answer in one of my variables.

Currently, my code looks like this

```
drinkchoice <- tibble(prop.table(table(surveyq$drink_choice)))
```

when running the code, it returns the proportion of each answer in the variable but does not list the answers that come with it. For example it returns a table looking like:

```
0.007
0.04
0.29
0.13
0.09
```

but when I remove tibble() from the original line of code, it responds back with

```
pepsi 0.007
fanta 0.04
sprite 0.29
brisk 0.13
coke 0.09
```

I was wondering if there is any way to code it so even when using the tibble() function, I can keep it so when the code runs it returns me back the answer with the correct proportion with it.

Edit: I added the line ~ tibble::rownames_to_column("Drink") and I was wondering whether it is possible to rewrite the numbers under the new column? As it would solve my problem

Comment: Hard to say without seeing surveyq, but I'd guess that the dataframe you started with has row names, and these are removed by tibble(). You can apply tibble::rownames_to_column() to your dataframe to convert the rownames to a column.

Comment: I added the line ~ tibble::rownames_to_column("Drink") and I was wondering whether it is possible to rewrite the number under the new column? As it would solve my problem

Comment: `data.frame(prop.table(table(surveyq$drink_choice)))` should solve your problem

Comment: Or compute the proportion explicitly with `library(dplyr)`: `survey %>% count(drink_choice) %>% mutate(prop = n / sum(n))`